# How do I upload info associated to different Model Types using AWS & GraphQL?

Tags: swift, graphql, aws-amplify

I have an app that I have been working on that allows users to upload a post and other users can send messages after seeing their post. I am using AWS Amplify as a backend and I am trying to store user messages in a DynamoDB table. I am able to successfully store user info in a DynamoDB table after they create an account and successfully upload a post. My problem starts when I try to message another user about their post.

I get this error after pressing send `` Failed to create graphql GraphQLResponseError<ChatMessage>: GraphQL service returned a successful response containing errors: [Amplify.GraphQLError(message: "The variables input contains a field name \'chatMessageAuthorId\' that is not defined for input object type \'CreateChatMessageInput\' ", locations: nil, path: nil, extensions: nil)] Recovery suggestion: The list of `GraphQLError` contains service-specific messages ``

My GraphQL Schema is the following:

```
type User 
  @model 
  @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, operations: [create, delete, update]}]) {
  id: ID!
  userSub: String!
  fullName: String!
  conversations: [ConvoLink] @connection(name: "UserLinks")
  messages: [ChatMessage] @connection(name: "UserMessages", keyField: "authorId")
  createdAt: String
  updatedAt: String
}

type Conversation
  @model
  @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, ownerField: "members" }]) {
  id: ID!
  messages: [ChatMessage] @connection(name: "ConvoMsgs", sortField: "createdAt")
  associated: [ConvoLink] @connection(name: "AssociatedLinks")
  name: String!
  members: [String!]!
  createdAt: String
  updatedAt: String
}

type ChatMessage 
  @model
  @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, ownerField: "authorId" }]) {
  id: ID!
  author: User @connection(name: "UserMessages", keyField: "authorId")
  authorId: String
  content: String!
  conversation: Conversation! @connection(name: "ConvoMsgs")
  messageConversationId: ID!
  createdAt: String
  updatedAt: String
}

type ConvoLink 
  @model(
    mutations: { create: "createConvoLink", update: "updateConvoLink" }
    queries: null
    subscriptions: null
  ) {
  id: ID!
  user: User! @connection(name: "UserLinks")
  convoLinkUserId: ID
  conversation: Conversation! @connection(name: "AssociatedLinks")
  convoLinkConversationId: ID!
  createdAt: String
  updatedAt: String
}
type Post @model 
 @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner, operations: [create, delete, update] }]) {
  id: ID!
  userSub: String!
  filename: String!
  description: String!
  dateUploaded: String!
}
```

And this is my Swift code to send a message to another user.

```
    @objc func sendMessage(){
        currentUserSub = AWSMobileClient.default().userSub!
        guard let message = messageBox.text else{return}
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
        let hourString = formatter.string(from: Date())
        let user = User(userSub: currentUserSub, fullName: userFullName)
        let conversation = Conversation(messages: List<ChatMessage>.init(), associated: List<ConvoLink>.init(), name: "Chat between \(currentUserSub) & \(otherUserSub)", members: [currentUserSub,otherUserSub], createdAt: hourString, updatedAt: hourString)
        
        let chatMessage = ChatMessage(author: user, authorId: currentUserSub, content: message, conversation: conversation, messageConversationId: "\(currentUserSub) & \(otherUserSub)", createdAt: hourString, updatedAt: hourString)
        
        _ = Amplify.API.mutate(request: .create(chatMessage)) { event in
            switch event {
            case .success(let result):
                switch result {
                case .success(let convo):
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        print("Successfully created the convo: \(convo)")
                        self.messageButton.setTitle("Message Sent", for: .normal)
                        self.messageButton.isEnabled = false
                    }
                case .failure(let graphQLError):
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        print("Failed to create graphql \(graphQLError)")
                        self.messageButton.setTitle("An error has occured, try again.", for: .normal)
                        //  self.checkIfOffline()
                    }
                }
            case .failure(let apiError):
                print("Failed to create a message", apiError)
                // self.checkIfOffline()
            }
        }
        
        hideKeyboard()
        print(message)
    }
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? I am fairly new to GraphQL and AWS.

Comment: Can you share what version of the Amplify iOS and Amplify CLI are you using? For the CLI version it's important to know what version you were using at the time you created and pushed your backend.

Comment: @DanielRochetti My Amplify CLI version is 4.24.3 and inside of my podfile.lock file says my Amplify iOS version is (1.0.4)